# Looping through raster symbology (.lyrx) files assigning and saving using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-pro, layer-file

I have a raster with 8 bands all meaning different wildfire behaviors.  There is a designated folder that holds the symbology for each (rate of spread, flamelength, etc).  From downloading from the gov. website to final product is quite a process (unzip, extract by mask, add symbology, reclassify, raster to polygon, calculate geometry) and I do it all the time so I'm trying to automate the process.

I'm stuck on looping thru taking one individual raster, assigning it one symbology, saving it, moving on to the next symbology.  I'm sure the code is pointed to the correct pathway and .lyrx but it keeps crashing.  Has anyone done this before?  Could it be the spaces in the symbology files?

code snippet:

```
        # Symbology folder
        symbology_folder = os.path.join(input_folder, "Symbology_ArcPro")

        # List of symbology layers- these are right, copied directly from the file pathway.  
        symbology_names = ["Rate of Spread (chains_hr)", "Flame Length (ft)", "Fireline Intensity (BTU_ft-sec)"]

        for symbology_name in symbology_names:
            symbology_path = os.path.join(symbology_folder, f"{symbology_name}.lyrx")

            # Create a folder for the symbology if it doesn't exist
            symbology_output_folder = os.path.join(output_folder, symbology_name)
            if not os.path.exists(symbology_output_folder):
                os.makedirs(symbology_output_folder)
                

            # Loop through the extracted rasters and apply symbology
            for raster in raster_list:
                assign_symbology_and_save(os.path.join(output_folder, raster), symbology_path, symbology_name)
```

Comment: I would make a few dummy files with no spaces or special characters. 

Or add `.replace() ` operations to your file names for save to eliminate these and see if it runs